# Missing or Insufficient permissions on Firestore Security Rule with get()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Pretty much no matter what I use for the get() request, getting `Missing or insufficent permissions` when logged in with a userID that is a "member":

```
function isSelf(userID) {
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userID
}

function isMember(userID) {
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/'members'/$(request.auth.uid)).data.parent == userID
}

match /templates/{userID} {
    allow read, write: if false
    
    match /templates/{templateID} {
        allow read: if isSelf(userID) || isMember(userID)
      allow write: if isSelf(userID)
      allow delete: if false
    }

    allow read: if isSelf(userID) || isMember(userID)
    allow write: if isSelf(userID)
  }
```

Have tried using get() with `.data.parent` and with `.parent` The member doc looks like this:

```
{
  parent: 'USER_ID_OF_PARENT'
}
```

Call from the client app is:

```
export const getTemplate = async ({ userID, form }) => {
 db.collection('templates').doc(userID).collection('templates').doc(form).get()
    .then((doc) => {
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Database structure is:

- **/templates/{userID}** is a collection of docs with ids as userIDs that correspond to a doc with matching userID in `/users/{userID}`
- **/members/{memberID}** is a collection of docs with ids as memberIDs, with a `parent` field with a string value `SOME_USER_ID` which matches a doc with userID `SOME_USER_ID` in `/users/{userID}`

**Example:**

`/members/'MEMBER_1'` doc:

```
{
  name: 'Member 1',
  parent: 'OWNING_USER_1'
}
```

`/users/'OWNING_USER_1'` doc:

```
{
  name: 'Owning User 1',
  parent: 'OWNING_USER_1'
}
```

`/templates/'OWNING_USER_1'` doc:

```
{
  // no fields
}
```

`/templates/'OWNING_USER_1'/templates/'FORM_1'` doc:

```
{
  name: 'Form 1'
}
```

With the following call:

```
getTemplate({
  userID: 'OWNING_USER_1',
  form: 'FORM_1'
})
```

1. When the authenticated user is OWNING_USER_1, the above call is **successful** (the `isSelf()` rule returns as true) and the found template document is returned
2. When the authenticated user is MEMBER_1, the above call gets `Missing or insufficient permissions` (the `isMember()` rule returns false)

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They only trigger when there is a request from the client app. Please edit the question to show that client code, so we can see how the rules will trigger.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Updated question @DougStevenson -- using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase package

Comment: Without seeing all the specific data in play here (the contents of all the variables, user IDs, and documents, there's not much that can be said.  Something is not lining up, and we need to be able to see what that is.  You might be helped in debugging this by using the local emulator.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: Just added more details on the database structure... does that help?

Comment: Not really.  We need to see all the variables in play.  Otherwise it's impossible to know how the rules are actually evaluating.  Hard code everything, including the query itself, and show actual documents with actual data.

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: @DougStevenson just added an answer-- had extra quotes around 'members' even though it's a directory in the get() function

Answer (score 1):

Removed the quotes from around 'members' and this is now working correctly:

Replaced:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/'members'/$(request.auth.uid)).data.parent`

with:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/members/$(request.auth.uid)).data.parent`